# Is there a way to prove that $x^n+x^m=C, x$ $\&$ $C \in ℝ, n$ $\&$ $m \in ℕ$ has no general solution for $x$?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I think I have made myself clear in the title and is hoping for someone to show this with as simple math as possible. Since I'm only 17 and haven't learned all of the complex mathematics yet.

However **if there is** a general solution for this, then try to prove that! :)

Comment: You mean, you want to show that given $n, m$ and $C$, there is no algebraic formula that gives you possible values of $x$ satisfying this equation, right?

Comment: To show that there is no way to give all the possible values of $x$ from an expression of $n,m$ and $C$.

Comment: This depends on $n,m,C$.  For example, $m=n=1$ has a unique general solution, namely $x=\frac{C}{2}$.

Comment: Yes but the solution must be __general__ for all values of $n,m$ and $C$.

Comment: Seeing as this seems fairly similar to the Abel-Ruffini theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) I suppose that its probably unlikely that (although I'm not ruling out the possibility that there is) a general solution exists, and that any proof showing that there is no such general formula would probably use some form of Galois theory. As for your desire for a "simple" proof, for such a general equation I think it would be very unlikely.

Comment: IIRC a Tschirnhaus transformation brings a general quintic to a form like $x^5-x-a=0$. So the non-solvability of a quintic (by the usual operations, i.e. excluding hypergeometric series and such) would be a consequence of the non-existence of a general formula for the solutions of your equation (in the special case $n=5$, $m=1$. Therefore I strongly suspect that Galois theory will be required.